# Generic component input enforces an interface - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to make a component that takes an input that can be of any type as long as it implements a specified interface. How can I do this?

For example, say that I have the following interface:

```
interface vehicle {
  cost: number;
  engine: string;
}
```

And I want to have a component that takes an input that implements the interface vehicle, but doesn't care that the actual type is a car vs a truck as it will not be using any properties on the vehicle other than those in the interface.

Comment: `@Input() myInput : vehicle;` it might be wise to prefix your interface types with `I` so that would be `IVehicle` instead of `vehicle`. Also many developers use pascal casing for their type names and camel casing for member names.

Comment: @Igor, thank you. I actually just typed that into Stack Overflow quickly as I can't post the code that I am working on. I also just found that my issue wasn't with using the interface directly, but the way in which I was importing the interface into the module was incorrect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that my issue wasn't actually with using the interface, but with the way that I was using my module. If anyone else is having an issue and comes across this question, you can use an interface in the same way that you would use a class for typing of your input properties.